# What does None mean in a control specification for Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, core-language

I am now struggling to understand [code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17081/) that contains the following (simplified) `Manipulate` structure.

```
Manipulate[
    complexparts[E^(I Pi t)],
 {{t, 1/4.}, 0., 2},
 {{complexparts, {Re[#], Im[#]} &}, None}]
```

I am having difficulty with the last line: `{{complexparts, {Re[#], Im[#]}&}, None}`. Somehow, this creates a "pure function" with a name "complexparts," which is then used above in the line

```
complexparts[E^(I Pi t)]
```

I tried to execute these independently outside the body of code so I could watch them do what they do, but without success. I evaluated:

```
{{complexparts, {Re[#], Im[#]} &}, None}
```

and then:

```
complexparts[x+Iy]
```

But my output was just:

```
complexparts(x+I y)
```

Can I get some help in understanding how `{{complexparts, {Re[#], Im[#]} &}, None}` works? And what does the word `None` do?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## What the first part of the variable declaration does

`Manipulate` initializes `complexparts` to `{Re[#], Im[#]} &` when it executes.  (In general, a declaration of the form `{{var, expr},...}` in a `Manipulate` results in the local variable `var` being initialized to `expr`.)  To use `complexparts` outside of the `Manipulate`, do this:

```
complexparts = {Re[#], Im[#]} &;
With[{θ = 0.25, b = 0.5 + 0.2 I},
 complexparts /@ {E^(I π θ), b E^(-I π θ), 
   E^(I π θ) + b E^(-I π θ), 0}]

(* {{0.707107, 0.707107}, {0.494975, -0.212132}, {1.20208, 0.494975}, {0, 0}} *)
```

## Addendum 1 -- What "None" does

To illustrate @Mr.Wizard's remark about `Initialization`, one could modify @David's code above as follows:

```
Manipulate[
 complexparts[E^(I Pi t)],
 {{t, 1/4.}, 0., 2},
 {complexparts, None},
 Initialization :> (complexparts = {Re[#], Im[#]} &)
]
```

The declaration `{complexparts, None}` declares `complexparts` to be a local variable of the `DynamicModule` that is created by the `Manipulate` command.  Whether `complexparts` needs to be declared local or not doesn't seem important in such an example.  Generally I try to localize variables whenever possible, especially in `Manipulate`, as it saves headaches if you're doing scratch work in the same kernel that the `Manipulate` uses.  Since the intended scope of `complexparts` is entire body of the `Manipulate` (and furthermore, it never changes), declaring it as a variable in a `Manipulate` seems appropriate.  It hardly matters here, but in some cases it can make a big difference.

**Update -- Reference to the manual**

I have found a passage in the [manual](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.en.html) which I believe documents the usage of `None`.  There are two alternatives for specifying a control type

```
{u, ..., ControlType -> type}
```

or more briefly

```
(u, ..., type}
```

This last one is not described but is used frequently in the examples.  Technically it has the form

```
{u, ..., func}
```

where `func` is a function that constructs the control; however, since `None` is not a function, one can object that `None` must be treated as a special case.  On the other hand, the reference page state

> Possible control types include: `Animator`.... `None` can also be used.

The effect of a variable declaration is described thus:

> Manipulate generates a DynamicModule object, with the variables u, v, etc. specified as local.

While the manual does not clearly state that `{u,..., None}` is accepted usage, it does state that what is practically equivalent, `{u,..., ControlType -> None}` is:

> Use `ControlType` to specify the type of control to use, including `None`:
>
> ```
> Manipulate[u, {u, 0, 1}, ControlType -> None]
> ```

## Addendum 2 -- "None" and other alternatives

In response to the updated title for @David's question, as well as to some of the comments, the following might be worth studying to see the differences.

*Problem.*  We need the variable `var` to be local.  It takes a long time to compute its value.  It won't change its value, but we need to dynamically access the value (or parts of the value).

As an example, `var` is to be a list of squares and the "long time" is simulated by `Pause[0.2]`.  We wish to display part `n` of `var` with the slider for `n`.  The solutions below all do the "same" thing.  But there are differences in how each works.  Depending on what one is trying to do, the differences can be significant.  In my opinion, #1 is the best; the others can be fine in appropriate situations.  I'll explain below.

```
(* 1 *)
Manipulate[
 var[[n]],
 {n, 1, 10, 1},
 {{var, Table[Pause[0.2]; n^2, {n, 10}]}, None}
]

(* 2 *)
Manipulate[
 var[[n]],
 {n, 1, 10, 1},
 {var, None},
 Initialization :> (var = Table[Pause[0.2]; n^2, {n, 10}])
]

(* 3 *)
Module[{var = Table[Pause[0.2]; n^2, {n, 10}]},
 Manipulate[
  var[[n]],
  {n, 1, 10, 1}
  ]
]

(* 4 *)
Manipulate[
 Module[{var = Table[Pause[0.2]; n^2, {n, 10}]},
  var[[n]]],
 {n, 1, 10, 1}
 ]
```

[image]

The most important thing to ask is when is `var` calculated in each solution above:

1. Once when the input cell is first evaluated.
2. Every time the `Manipulate` output is (re)activated.  For instance, every time the notebook is opened.
3. Once when the input cell is first evaluated. (Same as #1.)
4. Every time `n` changes value.  This is terrible.

The second question is where is `var` stored:

1. In the output cell (in the notebook) and loaded into the kernel.  Can make a very big notebook file, but the data is persistent.
2. In the output cell l (in the notebook) as in 1 (and overwritten by the `Initialization` code).  *Correction due to @unlikely.*
3. Just in the kernel, when the input cell is evaluated.  (Note the difference in #1.)
4. In the kernel, after recalculation.

Next, does the output work when the notebook is reopened?  Will it work as a CDF?  As a Wolfram Demonstration? (Each has the same answer for a given solution):

1, 2, 4: Yes.
3: No.  (Even if `var` were made global, a Demonstration must have `Manipulate` as the outside function.)

So in summary,

1. Fast, fast on re-open of notebook, quick start-up in a CDF.
2. Fast, slow on re-open, slow start-up in a CDF.  (Change pause to 5 seconds, and you'll see a problem.)
3. Fast, won't work on reopen, won't work in a CDF.
4. Super slow all the time.

*Now what's going on?*

In #1, the data is computed first and fed to `Manipulate`, which stores in the output.  That's what happens in `{{var, initial_value},..}`.

In #2, the `Initialization` code is stored unevaluated in the output.  Every time the output cell is activated (by opening the notebook and scrolling to the cell), the `Initialization` code is evaluated.

In #3, a local variable is first created in the kernel and initialized; the local id for `var` is stored in the `Manipulate` output.  When the notebook is reopened, this id is invalid.  You have to reevaluate the input again to get it to work.

In #4, a new local variable is created every time the Manipulate is updated (on start-up and every time a control is moved or a tracked variable changes); the variable is then initialized, so this can cost a lot a time.  When the initialization time is short, you won't really notice the difference between #1, #2, and #4.

Comment: @Artes, Thanks for the edit.  How do you get the Greek letters?

Comment: Take a look at aswers to this question : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/how-to-copy-as-unicode-from-a-notebook  In case that doesn't work or, you can always copy/paste Greek letters from other posts.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks. To be complete, I should have discussed what happens if you replace `Module` by `DynamicModule` -- #3 becomes like #1, except #3 still won't be acceptable as a Demonstration, but it adds a level of localization someone might desire.  #4 stays essentially the same, except some stuff gets stored in the front-end.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Hello Michael, it was nice to meet you. Pity that only once. Hope to see you next time too. :)

Comment: @Kuba Hi, it was nice to meet you, too, and too bad it was so brief.  Next time we should have an SE dinner or something. :)

Comment: I have some problem understanding your case 2. You state that var is stored in the kernel. It's not a DynamicModule-localized variable (as the case 1 and as n), that is stored in the "output cell and loaded from the kernel". Indeed I cnnot read the definition of var outside the Manipulate.

Comment: @unlikely  Thanks for checking. I'm not sure how that went unnoticed; I'm sure I checked. By "storing" I mean whether the value is stored permanently in the notebook or only in the kernel. In all cases `var` is also stored in the kernel while the Manipulate is running and can be accessed outside the Manipulate.  Prepend `var =.; Print[var];` at the beginning of the Initialization code.  You'll get the full symbol+context.  Something like ``FE`var$$123`.

Comment: I was facing problems in this area so I tried to get some insight. Thanks for the spending time to look again at this. I now understand what was  the meaning of what you said: I was confused because `??var` listed a `Global\`var` with no values. Indeed in your text you now confirm that, in case 2, `var` is persisted in the notebook but still initialized every time the notebook is opened. This appear to me a bit overkilling. Generally speaking, it is possible to state that the usage 2 is suitable when paired with `UnsavedVariables->{var}`?

Comment: @unlikely Yes, that does seem to be the case.  This may be worth mentioning in the answer, if I get another chance to update it.

Comment: Fo me this comment is enough. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I'm not surprised you're having trouble as `{{complexparts, {Re[#], Im[#]} &}, None}` is (to the best of my knowledge) a nonstandard "hack" and not part of the documented standard uses.  I have [used it myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8552728/618728) but I still don't recommend it.  Usually you can use the `Initialization` option instead.

Evaluating `{{complexparts, {Re[#], Im[#]} &}, None}` by itself outside of `Manipulate` doesn't do anything.  Rather, this is part of the syntax of `Manipulate` describing a parameter `complexparts` with a starting value of `{Re[#], Im[#]} &` and no control (`None`).

Comment: The use of `{var, None}` in `Manipulate` was taught to me by a Wolfram Demonstrations editor back in Mma V6.  `Manipulate` creates a `DynamicModule` with all the local variables declared at the end of the `Manipulate`, with controls attached to them unless you say `None`.  They sometimes seemed to prefer local variables to be used within a `Manipulate` to be declared that way.  The use of `None` is undocumented, but perhaps not nonstandard.  One can't always accomplish the same thing with `Initialization`.

Comment: @Michael Alright, that adds to the validity of the practice, and I agree that it is sometimes hard to do without (see linked answer).

Comment: I have added an argument to [my answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17112/what-does-none-mean-in-a-control-specification-for-manipulate/17113#17113) that this use of `None` was intended. Not exactly a watertight argument, but add to it that the usage works in practice, and I think it has some weight.

Answer (score 2):

That code you're pulling out of the Manipulate is just a list. `complexparts` is a blank symbol -- it's meaningless on its own. You may as well just type `{1, 2, 3, 4}`. The reason that code acquires meaning is because the `Manipulate` function *chooses to interpret* that list in a certain way. In other words, check the documentation for `Manipulate` to understand what that list means (within Mathematica, click on `Manipulate` and hit F1). That same list will mean something different in another context.

In this case remove the `None` and you'll see that the list is a manipulator/variable specification for `Manipulate`. The `None` is a meaningless symbol that `Manipulate` *chooses to interpret* to mean "don't show this control." So basically that list is just a weird way of declaring a variable within Manipulate. A variable that happens to be a function.

I'm not sure why that code is like that. You should just declare functions at the top or within a `Module`. Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
ReIm[c_] := {Re[c], Im[c]};

Manipulate[
 b = Complex @@ bmanipulate;

 Show[
  Graphics[GraphicsComplex[
    ReIm /@ {E^(I π θ), b E^(-I π θ), E^(I π θ) + b E^(-I π θ), 0},{
     Circle[4], {Red, Circle[4, Norm[b]]}, Arrow[{4, 1}],
     {Red, Arrow[{4, 2}]}, Line[{1, 3, 2}], {Dashed, Line[{4, 3}]}
     }], PlotRange -> 2, Axes -> True],

  ParametricPlot[
   ReIm[E^(I π t) + b E^(-I π t)], {t, 0, θ + 10^-6}], 
  ImageSize -> 250],

 {{ θ, 1/4.}, 0., 2},
 {{bmanipulate, {0.5, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, ControlPlacement -> Left}]
```

I'm not sure that the mathematical stuff stayed correct after I redid it, but in terms of the code it should be easier to follow.

(Small note. `b` here is a global variable because it's no longer a Manipulate variable. If you don't want variables leaking then use `Module` or `With`).

Comment: Why should one declare functions at the top or within a `Module`?  Do you think that rule applies only to functions or to other variables that are local, or constant, or something else?

Comment: By the way, the statement `b = Complex @@ bmanipulate` makes the output depend on both `b` and `bmanipulate`.  When `bmanipulate` is changed, the output is updated, which changes `b`, and in turn that triggers a second update.  Doesn't matter much when the output is computed as fast this one, but it makes the demonstration run half as fast.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks, that's pretty subtle. A better version would declare the b within Module or With. And regarding functions, I just mean that generally you should declare things before using them, for the purposes of readability. That's all.

Comment: Yes, it's odd that the variables in `Manipulate`, as well as the `Initialiation` code, come after use, whereas in `Module` etc. they come before.