# Incrementally revealing Grid (or TableForm) entries

Tags: list-manipulation, grid-layouts

I have a `Grid` (or `TableForm`) object like this

`Grid[{{Ins, Outs}, {a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}, Frame -> All]`

[image]

that I would like to "incrementally reveal" (within a `Manipulate`) in the sense, for example, that one row at a time is revealed with each click of the `Manipulate`.

The part giving me trouble is that I want to "fill in" the table from *bottom to top*, while maintaining the (final) header cells and grid lines throughout each incremental reveal.

I started out by filling the yet-to-revealed entries with white space (until they are revealed). This is fine for small tables like this, but I also need it to work for tables with dozens of rows so I am seeking something more systematic.

Any hints/tips/nudges would be appreciated.

**Edit:** To clarify, the desired behavior is like this:

```
one = Grid[{{Ins, Outs}, {, }, {, }, {e, f}}, Frame -> All];
two = Grid[{{Ins, Outs}, {, }, {c, d}, {e, f}}, Frame -> All];
three = Grid[{{Ins, Outs}, {a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}, 
  Frame -> All]; 
Manipulate[{one, two, three}[[i]], {i, {1, 2, 3}}]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe you just need double `InputField` with dynamic referrence to rows? I think wider contex is required.

Comment: @Kuba: The entries I'm wanting to reveal to the viewer are not input that the viewer provides (and that seems to be what `InputField` is for). Instead, the entries are values which have been computed "offline".

Comment: I see, something like this: `grid = {{Ins, Outs}, {a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}; Manipulate[ Grid[{First@grid, grid[[n]]}, Frame -> All] , {n, 2, Length@grid, 1}]` ?

Comment: Or this `grid[[;; n]]` instead of `{First@grid, grid[[n]]}`.

Comment: @Kuba post it :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard but is it what OP wants? :) There is also a possibility that full frame has to be visible but partially filled ;)

Comment: The desired behavior is like this (I know, the code is hideous): `one = Grid[{{Ins, Outs}, {, }, {, }, {e, f}}, Frame -> All];
two = Grid[{{Ins, Outs}, {, }, {c, d}, {e, f}}, Frame -> All];
three = Grid[{{Ins, Outs}, {a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}, Frame -> All];
Manipulate[{one, two, three}[[i]], {i, {1, 2, 3}}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My version:

```
data = {{Ins, Outs}, {a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};

Manipulate[
 m = data; m[[2 ;; n]] = {}; Grid[m, Frame -> All],
 {n, Length@data - 1, 1, -1},
 {m, None}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Is {m, None} only for scoping purposes? (+1)

Comment: @Kuba Correct.  I'll try to find the reference for that and update this comment when I do.  That was quick; [here it is](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17113/121).  I think that answer makes a good case for this being a reasonable practice.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit.** Clear version with `ConstantArray` but I like more the latter with `ArrayPad`.

```
Manipulate[
           Grid[
                Flatten[{
                         {grid[[1]]},
                         ConstantArray["", {n - 2, 2}],
                         grid[[n ;;]]
                        }, 1]
                , Frame -> All]
           , {n, 2, Length@grid, 1}]
```

`ArrayPad` seems to fit this job best :)

```
grid = {{Ins, Outs}}~Join~Partition[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 2];

Manipulate[
           Grid[{First@grid}~Join~ ArrayPad[Rest@grid[[n ;;]],
                                            {{n - 1, 0}, 0}, ""], 
                Frame -> All], 
            {n, 1, Length@grid - 1, 1}]
```

[image]

And the `SetterBar` version analogical as OP's.

```
Manipulate[
           Grid[{First@grid}~Join~ArrayPad[Rest@grid[[Length[grid] - n ;;]],
                                           {{Length[grid] - n - 1, 0}, 0}, ""],
                Frame -> All], 
           {n, Range[Length[grid] - 1], SetterBar}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, with that edit and then `{n, Length@grid - 1, 1, 1}`, it does what I as looking for. Thanks. I will leave it open for a little while to encourage other answers.

Comment: @JohnD I've fixed this :) just a second ago :)