# Altering layout and sizing of Manipulate controls?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I'm currently working on a display project using `Manipulate` and was wondering if there is a straightforward way to alter the placement of the control options that I use. For example, the following shows my issue:
[image: control area]

The `Manipulate` argument of concern is as follows:

```
Style["View Control", 16, Bold],
{{setter, True, ""}, {True -> "Zoom", False -> "Pan"}},
ControlPlacement -> Left,
```

I would just like the Zoom and Pan buttons of the SetterBar to be a bit larger and closer to centered if possible. I've messed with things like `Appearance` and `Alignment`, but haven't really had any luck with previous questions or my own efforts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you've got to take over placement manually.  First declare the variable `setter` with no control ([None](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17112/what-does-none-mean-in-a-control-specification-for-manipulate/17113#17113)).  Next add a `SetterBar`.  Put this inside a `Pane` so you can control placement.  The `ImageSize` of the `Pane` needs to be determined by hand.  You can use `ImageSize -> Full`, which makes it fill the width of the notebook window -- perhaps desirable or not.  You can `Style` the text how you wish.

```
Manipulate[setter,
 Delimiter, Style["View Control", 16, Bold],
 {{setter, True, ""}, None},
 Dynamic@Pane[
   SetterBar[Dynamic@setter,
     {True -> Style["Zoom", Larger], False ->  Style["Pan", Larger]}], 
   Alignment -> Center, ImageSize -> 100],
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you are really fighting the automatic decisions of `Manipulate`, you might consider doing everything yourself in a `DynamicModule`.  Many find it easier.  (Or just go with the default in `Manipulate`.)

Comment: I used to control the `SetterBar` elements with `f = Framed[#, Alignment -> Center, FrameStyle -> None, ImageSize -> {45, 25}] &;`. And then simply: `True -> f@"Zoom",...`. A little way around, but `SetterBar` has no `ItemSize` option.

Comment: @Kuba One of the Wolfram people once showed me how to use `Pane`, the way you used `Frame` (mapping it onto each item).