# Manipulate syntax

Tags: manipulate, formatting

I am trying to manipulate a plot of the Bernoulli roots as follows:

[image]

The following code clearly is not going to work, but I have included it in an effort to illustrate my meaning.

```
sol = Solve[N[Table[BernoulliB[n, z], {n, 20, 20}] == 0, 10]];
Manipulate[ListPlot[{{Re@z, Im@z} /. sol}], {roots, 1, 100}]
```

It is the {n, 20, 20} that I think I am having the trouble with - the 20 is obviously the variable I would like to manipulate, and {n, roots, roots} was all I could think of doing.

I am also unsure how to format the axes and point sizes so they remain constant throughout the manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
Manipulate[
 sol = Solve[N[Table[BernoulliB[n, z], {n, roots, roots}] == 0, 10]];
 ListPlot[{{Re@z, Im@z} /. sol}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}], {roots, 1, 100, 1}]
```

`PlotRange` is used to keep the axes constant.

Comment: Wonderful - thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
Manipulate[
       sol = Solve[N[BernoulliB[x, z] == 0, 10]];
       ListPlot[{{Re@z, Im@z} /. sol}] , {{x, 10}, 1, 100, 1}]
```

In case you meant to plot a range of n:

```
Manipulate[
     sol = Table[Solve[N[BernoulliB[n, z] == 0, 10]], {n, x, y}];
     ListPlot[ {Re@z, Im@z} /. sol]
       , {{x, 10}, 1, Dynamic[y], 1}, {{y, 12}, Dynamic[x], 100, 1}]
```

Comment: Great - many thanks, I will have to use plotRange on this as advised by Anon - but the code works well :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NSolve.html) and make the *vars* argument `z` instead of `10` and you'll notice a big improvement in performance, especially when `roots` is large.

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[{Re@z, Im@z} /. NSolve[BernoulliB[roots, z] == 0, z], 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}],
 {roots, 1, 100, 1}]
```

I got rid of the global variable `sol` because there are issues with having global variables in a `Manipulate`.  Those issues can be managed, but when possible, localize variables.  If you need `sol` to use in multiple places, then [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/With.html) or [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Module.html) is an appropriate way to localize a temporary variable.  `With` may be replaced by `Module` if `sol` needs to change its value several times during a single update.

```
Manipulate[
 With[{sol = NSolve[BernoulliB[roots, z] == 0, z]},
  ListPlot[{Re@z, Im@z} /. sol, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]
  ],
 {roots, 1, 100, 1}]
```

In some cases, it is better to localize a variable in the `DynamicModule` constructed by `Manipulate`.  This can be done by specifying the control type `None` (see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17112/what-does-none-mean-in-a-control-specification-for-manipulate/17113#17113) for some discussion):

```
Manipulate[
 sol = NSolve[BernoulliB[roots, z] == 0, z];
 ListPlot[{Re@z, Im@z} /. sol, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}],
 {roots, 1, 100, 1}, {sol, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {roots}]
```

We have to use `TrackedSymbols` or `Manipulate` will update twice for each change in `roots`: once when `roots` changes value and another time when `sol` changes value.  When `With` above is not appropriate, this tends to be my favorite way, although in this particular example, using `Module` instead of `With` is just as good.