# Correcting problems with the controls in a Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, cdf-format, gui-construction, interactive

I am developing a toy application to teach me how to generate a more complex CDF app. The current toy app is taking integral.

```
Manipulate[
  DynamicModule[{f = Sin[x], xR = 1, xL = 0, Res = 0.4596976941}, 
    Column[{
      InputField[Dynamic[xL], Number], 
      InputField[Dynamic[xR], Number], 
      InputField[Dynamic[f]], 
      Button["Calculate", 
        Dynamic[Res = 
          NumberForm[NIntegrate[f, {x, xL, xR}, WorkingPrecision -> nw], np];]], 
      InputField[Dynamic[Res]], 
      Dynamic[If[fp == True, Plot[f, {x, xL, xR}]]]}]], 
  {{np, 10, "NumberFormat"}, 10, 30, 1}, 
  {{nw, 16, "WorkingPrecision"}, 10, 30, 1}, 
  {{fp, True, "Plot the function"}, {False, True}, Checkbox}]
```

[image]

But there are some of the problems that I am trying to solve.

1. I would like to have name tags on the left or top of each of the input fields. `FieldHint` does not work.

   ```
   Manipulate[
     DynamicModule[{f, xR, xL, Res}, 
       Column[{
         InputField[Dynamic[xL], Number, FieldHint -> "Lower Limit"], 
         InputField[Dynamic[xR], Number, FieldHint -> "Upper Limit"], 
         InputField[Dynamic[f], FieldHint -> "Function"], 
         InputField[Dynamic[Res], FieldHint -> "Result"], 
         Button["Calculate", 
           Dynamic[Res = 
             NumberForm[NIntegrate[f, {x, xL, xR}, WorkingPrecision -> nw], np];]], 
         Dynamic[If[fp == True, Plot[f, {x, xL, xR}]]]}]], 
     {{np, 10, "NumberFormat"}, 10, 30, 1}, 
     {{nw, 16, "WorkingPrecision"}, 10, 30, 1}, 
     {{fp, False, "Plot the function"}, {False, True}, Checkbox}]
   ```

   [image]

   And I think having name tags would look much better even if the FieldHint approach were made to work.
2. I tried to make the plotting also part of the button, but it is not working (I simply moved the `]` at the end of the `Button` expression to the end of the plotting). Also, when I don't have the plot, I get a `Null`, which I don't like. Is there a way of getting rid off that? And how can I make the size of the plot bigger?
3. The last thing I could not figure it out is to limit `xL` and `xR` inputs to a number. I specified in the input field that the input is number but when I enter something not a number, I get an error. I expected it simply not to update (according to help documentation, "The input field will not be updated if the input is not of the specified type")

Comment: Your first issue with `FieldHint` looks like a bug: even `InputField["", Expression, FieldHint -> "Hint"]` does not work. Have you reported it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Row[{"xL", InputField[Dynamic[xL], Number]}, Spacer[5]]
```

or

```
Labeled[InputField[Dynamic[xL], Number], "xL", Left]
```

to label the input fields.

```
Manipulate[DynamicModule[{f = Sin[x], xR = 1, xL = 0, Res = 0.4596976941}, 
  Column[{Row[{"xL ", InputField[Dynamic[xL], Number]}, Spacer[5]], 
    Row[{"xR ", InputField[Dynamic[xR], Number]}, Spacer[5]], 
    Row[{"f  ", InputField[Dynamic[f]]}, Spacer[5]], 
    Button["Calculate", 
     Dynamic[Res =  NumberForm[NIntegrate[f, {x, xL, xR}, WorkingPrecision -> nw],
          np];]], Row[{"res", InputField[Dynamic[Res]]}, Spacer[5]], 
    Dynamic[If[fp == True, Plot[f, {x, xL, xR}]]]}]], 
   {{np, 10, "NumberFormat"}, 10, 30, 1}, 
   {{nw, 16, "WorkingPrecision"}, 10, 30, 1},
   {{fp, True, "Plot the function"}, {False, True}, Checkbox}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, you can use `Grid` instead of `Column` as follows:

```
Grid[{{"xL", InputField[Dynamic[xL], Number]},
      {"xR", InputField[Dynamic[xR], Number]}, 
      {"f",  InputField[Dynamic[f]]}, 
      {Button["Calculate",  Dynamic[Res = NumberForm[NIntegrate[f, {x, xL, xR},
        WorkingPrecision -> nw], np];]], SpanFromLeft},
      {"res", InputField[Dynamic[Res]]}, 
      {Dynamic[If[fp == True, Plot[f, {x, xL, xR}]]], SpanFromLeft}}]
```

To get rid of `Null` you can change the part `If[...]` in your code to

```
If[fp, Plot[f, {x, xL, xR}], ""]
```

Answer (score 1):

A few points and my version:

- `Manipulate[DynamicModule[{f = Sin[x],...` means whenever `Manipulate` updates itself, `f` etc. are reinitialized.  (It does this only first time the calculate button is pushed.)  I would suggest doing it all inside one `DynamicModule` or one `Manipulate`.  I show the `Manipulate` approach below.  I constructed the controls in the standard `Manipulate` way, which I thought I should do if I was going to use `Manipulate` at all.  (For control type `None`, see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17112/what-does-none-mean-in-a-control-specification-for-manipulate).)
- `NumberForm` messes up the output as displayed in the `InputField`, imo.  One can takes advantage of the internal rules by using [`SetPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html) instead.
- The option [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html) will control the size of many displayed objects, including `Plot`.  [`Pane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pane.html) is another construct that will control size.
- With respect to restricting `InputField`, `Manipulate` makes certain things automatic & easy and some things difficult to implement.  For this reason, some prefer to use `DynamicModule` and construct everything by hand, but exactly in the way desired.  To get `Number` into the second argument of `InputField` as a `Manipulate` control, you have to use the custom-control syntax, `{..., InputField[#, Number]&}`.
- To have a button control the updating, a standard trick is to use a dummy variable.  Restrict the [`TrackedSymbols`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackedSymbols.html) in `Manipulate` to it and any others that should cause an immediate update, leaving out parameters.  I included `fp`, which controls the plot; however, clicking it will also cause the integral to be updated.  One can use `Dynamic@If[...]` so that only the plot will be affected, but it will be replotted with the new settings, without updating the integral, if `fp` is clicked twice (off-on).

My code:

```
Pane[ (* controls overall width: sets the size of ImageSize -> Full, too *)
 Manipulate[
  update;
  Column[{
    Dynamic@If[fp == True,
      Plot[f, {x, xL, xR}, PlotLabel -> f, ImageSize -> Full],
      Graphics[{}, PlotLabel -> " ", ImageSize -> Full, 
       Options[Plot, AspectRatio]]],
    Button[
     Mouseover[Style["http://www.wolfram.com", "Hyperlink"], 
      Style["http://www.wolfram.com", "HyperlinkActive"]], 
     NotebookLocate[{URL["http://www.wolfram.com"], None}], 
     Appearance -> None]}
   ],

  Style["1D Definite Integral Calculator", "Function"],
  {{fp, True, "Plot the function"}, {False, True}, Checkbox, 
   ControlPlacement -> Bottom},
  {{np, 16, "NumberFormat"}, 5, 30, 1, ControlPlacement -> Bottom},
  {{nw, 16, "WorkingPrecision"}, 10, 30, 1, 
   ControlPlacement -> Bottom},
  {{xL, 0, "Lower Limit"}, InputField[#, Number, ImageSize -> Full] &},
  {{xR, 1, "Upper Limit"}, InputField[#, Number, ImageSize -> Full] &},
  {{f, Sin[x], "Function"}, InputField, ImageSize -> Full},
  Button[Style["Calculate", Green, Bold], 
   Res = SetPrecision[NIntegrate[f, {x, xL, xR}, WorkingPrecision -> nw], np];
   update = 1 - update],     (* triggers update *)
  {{Res, 0.4596976941318603`16, "Result"}, InputField, 
   Enabled -> False, ImageSize -> Full},
  {{update, 1}, None},
  TrackedSymbols :> {update, fp}],
 {350, Automatic}]    (* {width, height} of output *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am learning Mathematica and this is my only first week. So it takes sometime for me to understand all you suggested. You are right about the NumberForm and also ImageSize. I am working on understanding why using Manipulate DynamicModule at the same time would create a problem. Below I updated  my code with some improvements and additional questions.

Comment: @Erdem You're welcome. You've picked a somewhat complicated problem to start with. I learned by working my way through the first four tutorials under the "Tutorials" drop-down menu at the top of the [`Manipulate` docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html). Note that `Manipulate` constructs a `DynamicModule` for all its control variables.  Variables that need persistent values are best put there, with `ControlType -> None` if no control is needed. Temporary scratch variables can be nested inside a `DynamicModule` or `Module` as in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers. I made a little change to avoid the Null from the if statement. I carried the If statement in front of the InputField for the plot. 
by using the suggestions: to get the FullSize plot, fixed the " " marks in the result section. 
Create a function DGL to make the calculation. Next step is to create a package and use the package instead of the function (still having problems with that)

What I did and what I would like to be able to do are;

To overcome the issue of non-numeric input breaking the calculation I used xL and xR check variables with NumberQ and if statement. This is working for the DGL function but not plotting. For example when I input "a" for Lower Limit, I get an error message for calculation but plotting part is failing. I am not sure why NumberQ is not updated before the plotting. This might be due to using Manipulate and DynamicModule together. I am not sure. Maybe if I can return xLcheck and xRcheck from DGL function it will be ok but I don't know how to take out more than one variable from a function (Yet!!!). Even if I can do that I would like to understand why the way I am doing is not working.

Also I used IntegerPart and Re commands for WorkingPrecision and  SetPrecision.

I moved the function plotting checkbox inside the column.

```
Manipulate[DynamicModule[{f = Sin[x], xR = 1, xL = 0, 
Res = 0.4596976941318603`16}, Column[
{Style["1D Definite Integral Calculator", "Function"] logo,
 Row[{"Lower Limit ", InputField[Dynamic[xL], Number]}, Spacer[5]],
 Row[{"Upper Limit ", InputField[Dynamic[xR], Number]}, Spacer[5]],
 Row[{"Function  ", InputField[Dynamic[f]]}, Spacer[20]], 
 Button[Style["Calculate", Green, Bold], 
  Dynamic[Res = DGL[f, xR, xL, np, nw];]], 
 Row[{"Result", InputField[Dynamic[Res], Enabled -> False]}, 
  Spacer[51]],
 Row[{"Plot the Function ", Checkbox[Dynamic[fp], {False, True}]}],
 fp,
 xLcheck = NumberQ[xL], xRcheck = NumberQ[xR],
 If[fp == True && xLcheck == True && xRcheck == True, 
  InputField[
   Dynamic[Plot[f, {x, xL, xR}, Dynamic[PlotLabel -> f], 
     ImageSize -> Full]], FieldSize -> {30, 15}]],

  Button[
  Mouseover[Style["http://www.wolfram.com", "Hyperlink"], 
   Style["http://www.wolfram.com", "HyperlinkActive"]], 
  NotebookLocate[{URL["http://www.wolfram.com"], None}], 
  Appearance -> None]
 }]],{{np, 16, "NumberFormat"}, ControlPlacement -> Bottom},{{nw, 16, "WorkingPrecision"}, ControlPlacement -> Bottom},
 Initialization :> (
DGL[f_, xR_, xL_, np_, nw_] := Module[{xLcheck, xRcheck},
  xLcheck = NumberQ[xL];
  xRcheck = NumberQ[xR];
  If[xLcheck == True && xRcheck == True ,
   ResultTF = 
    SetPrecision[
     NIntegrate[f, {x, xL, xR}, 
      WorkingPrecision -> Re[IntegerPart[nw]]], 
     Re[IntegerPart[np]]], 
   "Enter numeric inputs for Lower and Upper Limits"]]
) ]
```

Thank you for the help again. I hope these will be helpful to other people too.