# Hiding a Manipulate slider

Tags: manipulate

I want to generate a different random initial condition for rule 110 using a Button for Manipulate, not a slider. How can I make the slider invisible here? I tried specifying `ControlType -> None`, and made the Button disappear.

```
 Manipulate[
 SeedRandom[seed];
 ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[110, RandomInteger[1, 600], 700]],
 { seed, 1, 1000, 1}, 
 Button["Randomize initial condition", 
  If [seed < 1000, seed = seed + 1, seed = seed - 1]]]
```

Comment: Did you do it like this?: `{seed, 1, 1000, 1, ControlType -> None}`

Comment: No, I tried: Manipulate[
 SeedRandom[seed];
 ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[110, RandomInteger[1, 600], 700]],
 { seed, 1, "", 1000, 1}, 
 Button["Randomize initial condition", 
  If [seed < 1000, seed = seed + 1, seed = seed - 1]], 
 ControlType -> None], and thanks, that works

Comment: Done.  And you're welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have no control for `seed` to appear, apply the option `ControlType -> None` to the variable:

```
 Manipulate[
 SeedRandom[seed];
 ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[110, RandomInteger[1, 600], 700]],
 {seed, 1, 1000, 1, ControlType -> None}, 
 Button["Randomize initial condition", 
  If [seed < 1000, seed = seed + 1, seed = seed - 1]]]
```

Comment: Note also that `{seed, 1, 1000, 1, None}` will suffice.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Yes, an explanation may be found in my answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17113), which was a question prompted by my use of it [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17081).  At some point since that time, I decided to use the longer form, at least on this site, because it occurs in the documentation and is more readable.